# 3 dif cols all of them with different date formats, efficient way to uniform?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

so, I got 3 different cols, referring to dates, with different formats, like this:

```
            col A|           colB|        colC
    0   1512086400000000    20180109    12/23/2017
    1   1514851200000000    20180109    1/10/2018   
    2   1512086400000000    20180109    12/27/2017  
    3   1514851200000000    20180109    1/27/2018
```

They are all **object type**, but I'd like them to become datetime, hopefully, all in the same format, similar to this **%d/%m/%yyyy**. What's the most efficient way in **python**?

Thank you all very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python/ pandas for datetimes is always same format - `YYYY-MM-DD`, for convert use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['colA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['colA'], unit='us')
df['colB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['colB'], format='%Y%m%d')
df['colC'] = pd.to_datetime(df['colC'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

print (df)

        colA       colB       colC
0 2017-12-01 2018-01-09 2017-12-23
1 2018-01-02 2018-01-09 2018-01-10
2 2017-12-01 2018-01-09 2017-12-27
3 2018-01-02 2018-01-09 2018-01-27

print (df.dtypes)
colA    datetime64[ns]
colB    datetime64[ns]
colC    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

If need format `dd/mm/yyyy` it is possible, but lost datetimes:

```
df['colA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['colA'], unit='us').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df['colB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['colB'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df['colC'] = pd.to_datetime(df['colC'], format='%m/%d/%Y').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

print (df)
        colA        colB        colC
0  01/12/2017  09/01/2018  23/12/2017
1  02/01/2018  09/01/2018  10/01/2018
2  01/12/2017  09/01/2018  27/12/2017
3  02/01/2018  09/01/2018  27/01/2018

print (df.dtypes)
colA    object
colB    object
colC    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: thank you very much, so there's no way to do it %d/%m/%yyyy?

Comment: @BeneditaMontenegro - If need datetimes then no, if need strings, add `.dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')`

Comment: really appreciate all your effort :), could u think of any major problems of losing datetime?

Comment: @BeneditaMontenegro - All datetimelike functions failed :(

Comment: Well, i'm still working with the dataframe, for now, I don't think I'll have problems with that, But in the future, if i have, i'll figure it out. I just want to thank you, once more, I was having a hard time on these, and learned a lot with ur post. thanks!

Comment: @BeneditaMontenegro - You are welcome :) Happy coding ;)